# Jupyter fails to load due to missing js files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed jupyter via pip

```
pip install jupyter
```

I can start it with

```
jupyter notebook
```

but (chrome and iexplore) cast an MIME error

[image]

The `AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime` folder only contains some json and html files, nothing more.

I also tried

```
pip uninstall jupyter
pip install jupyter
```

PS: I currently use

> Python 3.7.2
>   pip 19.0.3
>   jupyter 4.4.0

Comment: did you try reinstalling

Comment: yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that

Comment: are you facing the same problem while using firefox

Comment: Sadly no, but I'm sure its not browser related. Company policy, only chrome and ie allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently this issue is known. For everybody landing here instead of github, here is the solution

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467

The problem is in the **notebook** package, not jupyter.